# Mapbox/Leaflet .bottom controls being rendered above map and out of sight

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, mapbox

I'm having a very strange display error where the bottom controls are flipped up above the map, but out of the view of the map.  [This link](https://beekon-staging.herokuapp.com/activities/27/3d) demonstrates the issue.  If you inspect the map, you will see that both the Mapbox logo and the required attribution exist and are sized, but they were rendered above the map and out of sight.  This occurs to anything I try to place as a bottom control.

Using Bootstrap and Rails 4.2 as backend.  Relevant code:

## html

(Notes: (1) In debugging I tried to simplify the map, and just set a style.  Normally, it would use the .map .pad2 and .col-sm-12 within a .row div.  Change had no effect on the error. (2) the class names given to the body element reflect the controller invoking the page, which gives me control over which javascript files I render.  There are no css attributes assigned to them.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.0/mapbox.js"></script>
  <link href="//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.0/mapbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <title><%= @title || "Beacon" %></title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class = "<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
      <div id='map' style="width:900px; height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## elevation.css

```
#map3d {
    overflow:visible;
}

#map3d,
#map3d * {
    -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

#maprotor {
    -webkit-perspective: 1200;
    -moz-perspective:1200px;
    perspective: 1200;
    overflow:hidden;


    /* added */
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); 
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    height: calc(100vh - 142px); 

}

.leaflet-container {
    background:none;
}

.tilted {
    /* transition times placed in here to avoid transitions of polyline during map scroll */
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transform:rotateX(60deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(60deg)
}

.bottomcap{
    background:#30a07A;
}

.markercircle {
    width:4px;
    height:4px; 
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:-2px; 
    background:#60d0aA;
}


.leaflet-marker-pane, 
.leaflet-overlay-pane,
.leaflet-control-container {
    -moz-transform: translateZ(1px);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
}

.markerline {
    width:6px; 
    margin-left:-2px;
    background:#30a07A;
    height:0px; 
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-in;
    transition:height 0.2s ease-in;
}

.elevations {
    opacity:0.5;
    display:none;
}

.elemarker {
    -moz-transform:rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin:top center;
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:top center;
    margin:6px;
}

.tilted .elevations {
    display:block
}

/* Hover css */

 .elevations:hover {
    opacity:1;
 }
.elevations:hover .elefigure {
    display:inline-block; 
    width:60px; 
    text-align:center;
}
.elevations:hover .elefigure:after {
    content:'';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    display:inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:45%;
    text-align:center;
    border-top: 5px solid purple;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
.elevations:hover .markerline,
    .elevations:hover .bottomcap {
      background:#551A8B;
}
.elevations:hover .markercircle {
    background:#cea2f7;
}
.elefigure {
    -moz-transform:rotateX(180deg) translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg) translateX(-50%);
    margin-top:10px; 
    display:none; 
    color:white;
    background:purple; 
    padding:0px 4px; 
    border-radius:3px;
}

/* Style for button over map */
.pin-topleft {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
}

.pin-bottomleft {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

.message-box {
    opacity:0.7;
    background:#404040;
    color:#f8f8f8;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

## activity_graph.css

```
body {
  background:#404040;
  color:#f8f8f8;
  font:500 20px/26px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  height:100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background:#404040;
  color:#f8f8f8;
  height: calc(100vh - 142px);
}

.top-panel {
    background:#837E7C;
    color:#F8F8F8;

    padding: 5px;   
}

.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

.dialog-map {
    height: 250px;
    color: #404040;
}


.map {
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
  position:absolute;
  background:#404040;
  color:#404040;
  height: calc(100vh - 142px);
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}

.pad1{
    padding:10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
}

.pad2 {
  padding:20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
}

.fill {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.search-ui {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    z-index:1000;
}

.activity-row {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.activity-row-highlight {
    background: #666666 
}

.close-white {
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity: .8;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.image_size_thumbnail {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

## L.Control.Window.css

```
.leaflet-control-window-wrapper{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nonmodal{
    z-index: 6000;
}

.modal{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 7000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.visible {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

.leaflet-control-window{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 8px;

    /** BOX SHADOW **/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.control-window{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #353535;
    font: 14px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.leaflet-control-window .titlebar{
    min-height: 38px;
    cursor: grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    padding: 10px 45px 10px 10px;
}

.leaflet-control-window .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font: 16px/14px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:30;

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;


    color: #e4e4e4;
    font-size: 22pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0.9em;
}

.leaflet-control-window .close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.leaflet-control-window .content{
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    z-index:29;
    overflow: auto;
}

.leaflet-control-window .promptButtons{
    text-align: right;
    padding: 16px;
}

.leaflet-control-window button{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;

    opacity: 0.5;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;

    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 12px 8px 0 8px;
}

.leaflet-control-window button:focus {
    outline:0;
}

.leaflet-control-window button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

## railsbricks_custom.scss

```
//***********************************************************
// BOOTSTRAP VARIABLES OVERRIDES

// Color system
$brand-primary: #f75d59;
$brand-success: #5cb85c;
$brand-warning: #f0ad4e;
$brand-danger: #d9534f;
$brand-info: #5bc0de;

// Body scaffolding
$body-bg: #ffffff;
$text-color: #373737;
$link-color: $brand-primary;
$link-hover-color: darken($link-color, 15%);

// Typography
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700);
$font-family-sans-serif: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$font-family-serif: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
$font-family-monospace: 'Menlo','Monaco','Consolas','Courier New', monospace;
$font-family-base: $font-family-sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 14px;

// Headings
$headings-font-family: $font-family-base;
$headings-font-weight: 700;
$headings-color: inherit;

// Code blocks
$code-color: #c7254e;
$code-bg: #f9f2f4;
$pre-color: #373737;
$pre-bg: #f5f5f5;
$pre-border-color: #cccccc;

// Components: Padding
$padding-base-vertical: 6px;
$padding-large-vertical: 10px;
$padding-small-vertical: 5px;
$padding-base-horizontal: 12px;
$padding-large-horizontal: 16px;
$padding-small-horizontal: 10px;

// Components: Rounded corners
$border-radius-base: 4px;
$border-radius-large: 6px;
$border-radius-small: 3px;

// Components: Active state
$component-active-color: #ffffff;
$component-active-bg: $brand-primary;

// Components: Carets
$caret-width-base: 4px;
$caret-width-large: 5px;

// Buttons: Global
$btn-font-weight: normal;
$btn-link-disabled-color: #cccccc;

// Buttons: Default
$btn-default-color: #2C3539;
$btn-secondary-color: #ffffff;
$btn-default-bg: #ffffff;
$btn-default-border: #cccccc;

// Buttons: Primary
$btn-primary-color: $btn-secondary-color;
$btn-primary-bg: $brand-primary;
$btn-primary-border: darken($btn-primary-bg, 5%);

// Buttons: Info
$btn-info-color: $btn-secondary-color;
$btn-info-bg: $brand-info;
$btn-info-border: darken($btn-info-bg, 5%);

// Buttons: Warning
$btn-warning-color: $btn-secondary-color;
$btn-warning-bg: $brand-warning;
$btn-warning-border: darken($btn-warning-bg, 5%);

// Buttons: Danger
$btn-danger-color: $btn-secondary-color;
$btn-danger-bg: $brand-danger;
$btn-danger-border: darken($btn-danger-bg, 5%);

// Form states and alerts
$state-success-text: #468847;
$state-success-bg: #dff0d8;
$state-success-border: darken($state-success-bg, 5%);

$state-warning-text: #c09853;
$state-warning-bg: #fcf8e3;
$state-warning-border: darken($state-warning-bg, 3%);

$state-danger-text: #b94a48;
$state-danger-bg: #f2dede;
$state-danger-border: darken($state-danger-bg, 3%);

$state-info-text: #3a87ad;
$state-info-bg: #d9edf7;
$state-info-border: darken($state-info-bg, 7%);

// Alerts: Base styles
$alert-padding: 15px;
$alert-border-radius: $border-radius-base;
$alert-link-font-weight: bold;

// Alerts: Warning
$alert-warning-text: $state-warning-text;
$alert-warning-bg: $state-warning-bg;
$alert-warning-border: $state-warning-border;

// Alerts: Success
$alert-success-text: $state-success-text;
$alert-success-bg: $state-success-bg;
$alert-success-border: $state-success-border;

// Alerts: Danger
$alert-danger-text: $state-danger-text;
$alert-danger-bg: $state-danger-bg;
$alert-danger-border: $state-danger-border;

//Alerts: Info
$alert-info-text: $state-info-text;
$alert-info-bg: $state-info-bg;
$alert-info-border: $state-info-border;

// Navbar: Base styles
$navbar-height: 50px;
$navbar-margin-bottom: 4px;
$navbar-padding-horizontal: 15px;
$navbar-padding-vertical: 13px;
$navbar-border-radius: 0px;

// Navbar: Default navbar
// -> Basics
$navbar-default-color: #777777;
$navbar-default-bg: #f8f8f8;
$navbar-default-border: darken($navbar-default-bg, 7%);
// -> Links
$navbar-default-link-color: #777777;
$navbar-default-link-hover-color: #333333;
$navbar-default-link-hover-bg: $navbar-default-bg;
$navbar-default-link-active-color: #555555;
$navbar-default-link-active-bg: darken($navbar-default-bg, 7%);
$navbar-default-link-disabled-color: #cccccc;
$navbar-default-link-disabled-bg:$navbar-default-bg;
// -> Brand
$navbar-default-brand-color: $navbar-default-link-color;
$navbar-default-brand-hover-color: darken($navbar-default-brand-color, 10%);
$navbar-default-brand-hover-bg: $navbar-default-bg;
// -> Toggle
$navbar-default-toggle-hover-bg: #dddddd;
$navbar-default-toggle-icon-bar-bg: #cccccc;
$navbar-default-toggle-border-color: #dddddd;

// Navbar: Inverted navbar
// -> Basics
$navbar-inverse-color: #eeeeee;
$navbar-inverse-bg: #65797F;
$navbar-inverse-border: darken($navbar-inverse-bg, 7%);
// -> Links
$navbar-inverse-link-color: #eeeeee;
$navbar-inverse-link-hover-color: #ffffff;
$navbar-inverse-link-hover-bg: $navbar-inverse-bg;
$navbar-inverse-link-active-color: #ffffff;
$navbar-inverse-link-active-bg: darken($navbar-inverse-bg, 7%);
$navbar-inverse-link-disabled-color: #444444;
$navbar-inverse-link-disabled-bg:$navbar-inverse-bg;
// -> Brand
$navbar-inverse-brand-color: $navbar-inverse-link-color;
$navbar-inverse-brand-hover-color: #ffffff;
$navbar-inverse-brand-hover-bg: $navbar-inverse-bg;
// -> Toggle
$navbar-inverse-toggle-hover-bg: #333333;
$navbar-inverse-toggle-icon-bar-bg: #ffffff;
$navbar-inverse-toggle-border-color: #333333;

// Nav: Default nav
// -> Common values
$nav-link-padding: 10px 15px;
$nav-link-hover-bg: #eeeeee;
$nav-disabled-link-color: #cccccc;
$nav-disabled-link-hover-color: #cccccc;
$nav-open-link-hover-color: #ffffff;
$nav-open-caret-border-color: #ffffff;
// -> Pills
$nav-pills-active-link-hover-color: #ffffff;
$nav-pills-active-link-hover-bg: $component-active-bg;
// -> Tabs
$nav-tabs-border-color: #dddddd;
$nav-tabs-link-hover-border-color: #eeeeee;
$nav-tabs-active-link-hover-color: #bbbbbb;
$nav-tabs-active-link-hover-bg: $body-bg;
$nav-tabs-active-link-hover-border-color: #dddddd;
$nav-tabs-justified-link-border-color: #dddddd;
$nav-tabs-justified-active-link-border-color: $body-bg;

// Tables
// -> Default padding for <th>s and <td>s
$table-cell-padding: 8px;
// -> Default padding cells in .table-condensed
$table-condensed-cell-padding: 5px;
// -> Default background color used for all tables.
$table-bg: $body-bg;
// -> Background color used for .table-striped.
$table-bg-accent: #f9f9f9;
// -> Background color used for .table-hover.
$table-bg-hover: #f5f5f5;
// -> Border color for table and cell borders.
$table-border-color: #dddddd;

// Forms
// -> Inputs
$input-color: $text-color; // Text color for <input>s
$input-bg: #ffffff; // <input> background color
$input-border: #cccccc; // <input> border color
$input-border-radius: $border-radius-base; // <input> border radius
$input-color-placeholder: #bbbbbb; // Placeholder text color
// -> Input states
$input-border-focus: #66afe9; // Border color for inputs on focus
$input-bg-disabled: #dddddd; // <input disabled> background color
// -> Input sizes
$input-height-base: 38px; // Default .form-control height
$input-height-large: 46px; // Large .form-control height
$input-height-small: 28px; // Small .form-control height
// -> Legend
$legend-color: #aaaaaa;
$legend-border-color: #e5e5e5;
// -> Input groups
$input-group-addon-bg: #cccccc; // Background color for textual input addons
$input-group-addon-border-color: $input-border; // Border color for textual input addons

// Dropdowns
// -> Dropdown menu
$dropdown-bg: #ffffff; // Dropdown menu background color
$dropdown-border: #373737; // Dropdown menu border color
$dropdown-fallback-border: #cccccc; // Dropdown menu border color for IE8
$dropdown-caret-color: #dddddd; // Indicator arrow for showing an element has a dropdown
$dropdown-divider-bg: #e5e5e5; // Dropdown divider top border color
$dropdown-header-color: #dddddd; // Text color for headers within dropdown menus
// -> Dropdown items
$dropdown-link-color: $text-color; // Dropdown text color
$dropdown-link-hover-color: darken($dropdown-link-color,5%); // Hovered dropdown menu entry text color
$dropdown-link-hover-bg: #f5f5f5; // Hovered dropdown menu entry text color
$dropdown-link-active-color: $component-active-color; // Active dropdown menu entry text color
$dropdown-link-active-bg: $component-active-bg; // Active dropdown menu entry background color
$dropdown-link-disabled-color: #dddddd; // Disabled dropdown menu entry background color

// Panels and wells
// -> Common panel styles
$panel-bg: #ffffff;
$panel-inner-border: #dddddd; // Border color for elements within panels
$panel-border-radius: $border-radius-base;
$panel-footer-bg: #f5f5f5;
// -> Contextual panel colors
// --> Default
$panel-default-text: #373737;
$panel-default-border: #dddddd;
$panel-default-heading-bg: #f5f5f5;
// --> Primary
$panel-primary-text: #ffffff;
$panel-primary-border: $brand-primary;
$panel-primary-heading-bg: $brand-primary;
// --> Success
$panel-success-text: $state-success-text;
$panel-success-border: $state-success-border;
$panel-success-heading-bg: $state-success-bg;
// --> Info
$panel-info-text: $state-info-text;
$panel-info-border: $state-info-border;
$panel-info-heading-bg: $state-info-bg;
// --> Warning
$panel-warning-text: $state-warning-text;
$panel-warning-border: $state-warning-border;
$panel-warning-heading-bg: $state-warning-bg;
// --> Danger
$panel-danger-text: $state-danger-text;
$panel-danger-border: $state-danger-border;
$panel-danger-heading-bg: $state-danger-bg;
// -> Wells
$well-bg: #f5f5f5;

// Jumbotron
$jumbotron-padding: 30px;
$jumbotron-bg: #cccccc;
$jumbotron-font-size: ceil($font-size-base * 1.5);
$jumbotron-color: $text-color;
$jumbotron-heading-color: $headings-color;

// Carousel
$carousel-text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #373737;
$carousel-control-color: #ffffff;
$carousel-caption-color: #ffffff;
$carousel-indicator-border-color: #ffffff;
$carousel-indicator-active-bg: #ffffff;

// Labels
$label-color: #ffffff; // Default label text color
$label-link-hover-color: #ffffff; // Default text color of a linked label
$label-default-bg: #cccccc; // Default label background color
$label-primary-bg: $brand-primary; // Primary label background color
$label-success-bg: $brand-success; // Success label background color
$label-info-bg: $brand-info; // Info label background color
$label-warning-bg: $brand-warning; // Warning label background color
$label-danger-bg: $brand-danger; // Danger label background color

// Close button
$close-font-weight: bold;
$close-color: #000000;
$close-text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;

// Type
$text-muted: #bbbbbb; // Text muted color
$abbr-border-color: #cccccc; // Abbreviations and acronyms border color
$headings-small-color: #bbbbbb; // Headings small color
$blockquote-small-color: #cccccc; // Blockquote small color
$blockquote-border-color: #eeeeee; // Blockquote border color
$page-header-border-color: #eeeeee; // Page header border color

// Other
$hr-border: #cccccc; // Horizontal line color
$component-offset-horizontal: 180px; // Horizontal offset for forms and lists

//***********************************************************
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";

//***********************************************************
// CLASSES FOR VISUAL TESTING
.test1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.test2 {
  background-color: red;
}
.test3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
//***********************************************************

//***********************************************************
// APPLICATION-WIDE
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

blockquote{
  font-size: $font-size-base;
  font-style: italic;
}

.monospaced-control{
  font-family: $font-family-monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.center-block{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
//***********************************************************

//***********************************************************
// SPACING
$space-lg: 60px;
$space-md: 40px;
$space-sm: 20px;
$space-xs: 10px;

.space-top-lg{
  margin-top: $space-lg;
}
.space-top-md{
  margin-top: $space-md;
}
.space-top-sm{
  margin-top: $space-sm;
}
.space-top-xs{
  margin-top: $space-xs;
}

.space-bottom-lg{
  margin-bottom: $space-lg;
}
.space-bottom-md{
  margin-bottom: $space-md;
}
.space-bottom-sm{
  margin-bottom: $space-sm;
}
.space-bottom-xs{
  margin-bottom: $space-xs;
}

.space-left-lg{
  margin-left: $space-lg;
}
.space-left-md{
  margin-left: $space-md;
}
.space-left-sm{
  margin-left: $space-sm;
}
.space-left-xs{
  margin-left: $space-xs;
}

.space-right-lg{
  margin-right: $space-lg;
}
.space-right-md{
  margin-right: $space-md;
}
.space-right-sm{
  margin-right: $space-sm;
}
.space-right-xs{
  margin-right: $space-xs;
}

.space-all-lg{
  margin: $space-lg;
}
.space-all-md{
  margin: $space-md;
}
.space-all-sm{
  margin: $space-sm;
}
.space-all-xs{
  margin: $space-xs;
}

//***********************************************************

//***********************************************************
// FLASH MESSAGES
.alert {
  margin-top: -4px;
}
//***********************************************************

//***********************************************************
// NAVBAR
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: inherit;
}
//***********************************************************

//***********************************************************
// ERRORS
#error_explanation {
  color: $brand-danger;
  ul {
    margin-left: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }

  h2 {
    display:none;
  }
}

.error-text {
  color: $brand-danger;
}

.field_with_errors {
  .form-control {
    border: 1px solid $brand-danger;
  }
  label {
    color: $brand-danger;
  }
}
//***********************************************************

//***********************************************************
// IMAGES
img {
  @extend .img-responsive;
}

.img-inline{
  display: inline;
}

.img-block{
  display: block;
}

.img-framed{
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.img-title{
  color: #bbbbbb;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

//***********************************************************

//***********************************************************
// VIDEO
.js-video {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 67.5%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #cccccc;
  border: 3px solid #373737;

}

.js-video.widescreen {
  padding-bottom: 57.25%;
}

.js-video.vimeo {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.js-video embed, .js-video iframe, .js-video object, .js-video video {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
//***********************************************************


//***********************************************************
// FOOTER
#footer {
  background-color: #65797F;
  color: #eeeeee;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;

  .footer-first-row {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

## activity_show.js

```
markerGroup = L.featureGroup([]);
L.mapbox.accessToken = '...';  //value removed
map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.run-bike-hike');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find it in the code you posted but in your [CSS file](https://beekon-staging.herokuapp.com/assets/application-66e2de0a2666f3e1929f84a2653b72dc51cf0b2c619f608afb46f7d5f99223ff.css) i found the following which causes your problem:

```
.leaflet-marker-pane,
.leaflet-overlay-pane,
.leaflet-control-container {
    -moz-transform:translateZ(1px);
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(1px)
}
```

Comment: blast, I did forget one file -- I'm sorry if that troubled you.  I'm assessing whether it fixed it -- it appears to actually have worked on one page(!), but not on another (specifically, the one I directed you to).  Let me deploy again and see if anything changes.

Comment: the 3d stuff was the issue -- will have to figure out how to get it to work right.  Thank you again